# How to start camera intent without accelerometer sensor?

Tags: android, camera, orientation, accelerometer, sensors

I'm currently writing a application that needs to capture some images. I start the camera application using a intent like this:

```
if (v.equals(btnCap)) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
    }
```

The problem is: When i tilt my device, the buttons on the camera still change their orientation and the picture I receive is not in portrait.

Does anyone know how to capture a image in portrait mode, even if the device is tilted?

Thanks in advance, 
Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You best option is to create your own camera app (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera).

And then, in your AndroidManifest.xml, add the `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` option on the declaration of your activity.

It's better to build your own camera activity, because you can have issues for getting the pictures depending on the device model. I once had an issue with Samsung devices (see [Android Samsung: Camera app won't return intent.getData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989010/android-samsung-camera-app-wont-return-intent-getdata))

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I thought about building my own camera app, but I'm new to this and thought it would be better to start with some easier things :)

Comment: I started building my own camera in a new activity. Unfortunately I got in trouble loading/saving the bitmap. I don't know where to save or load the pictures. I used the method recommended in the developer guide you posted before.

Answer (score 1):

use  [setDisplayOrientation (int degrees)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29) it will make the job

if you are using you own camera you can use it like this

```
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1193#c42

Comment: where do i put this line of code? This method is from Camera class isn't it?