# onActivityResult returned from a camera, Intent null

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I follow the instruction on Camera on [Android dev site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera)

I just start the Camera Intent, not build my own camera.

The sample code to handle result return after taking a photo is as follows.

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                    data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }
    }

    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Video captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to:\n" +
                    data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the video capture
        } else {
            // Video capture failed, advise user
        }
    }
}
```

`resultCode` is OK, but `data` is always NULL, which causes a NPE. I looked into the sdcard, the photo was really saved there. Any tip? tks much.

Update: logcat info as requested:

```
   01-28 19:39:00.547: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24315): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.CameraTest/com.example.CameraTest.MyCamera}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.CameraTest/com.example.CameraTest.MyCamera}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2455)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1997)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3362)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:127)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1162)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.CameraTest/com.example.CameraTest.MyCamera}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2991)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
    ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.CameraTest.MyCamera.onActivityResult(MyCamera.java:71)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4654)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2987)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Post some more code and logcat also.

Comment: Did you use MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT ?

Comment: Grishu: updated. 
blackbelt: yes.

Comment: How are you passing the image path in intent please show ?

Comment: `private void fireCameraForImage(int requestCode){
       
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); 
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); 
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }`

Comment: @TungMaiLe Just use `fileUri` to get the image path. If you want to get the data path by default path, don't put `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`

Comment: Tks Sieryuu, but why is the Intent `data`  null?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem with your code is this:

```
data.getData()
```

This call does not get the **extra with the key "data"** from the returned `Intent`. It gets the field `data` from the returned `Intent` which is probably `null`.

You need to get the extra from the returned `Intent` like this:

```
data.getExtras().get("data");
```

Some of the other answers have indicated this, embedded in tons of other code. That makes it difficult to actually see what the problem is.

Comment: I have the same error, and in this case, the `data` parameter is null, so performing `data.getExtras()` in your answer still produces a NPE

Comment: I have the same issue. In some of the Samsung device, i got data parameter null. so, I can not move ahead.

Comment: @JigneshM.Mehta did you see KJ50's answer regarding Samsung phones?

Comment: @David Wasser: Still I got fileUri.toString() Null with KJ50's answer.. :(

Comment: @JigneshM.Mehta Please open a new question, post your problem, your code, etc. and maybe someone can help you. This isn't the right place to ask for assistance (in a comment of an answer).

Answer (score 8):

[Here is the answer from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4989163/1092403). It seems like it might be a problem with Samsung phones...

Basically, if you have [code like this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-image) which creates the Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

// start the image capture Intent
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then, in `onActivityResult`, **replace `data.getData()` with `fileUri.toString()` and it will solve your problem.**

Comment: And I am sometimes getting fileUri as null.

Comment: fileUri.toString() is also not working for samsung mobiles. :'(

Comment: Thank you > = forever (for real)

Comment: Btw, add Nexus-7 tablet (and Cyanogenmod OS) to the Samsung phones.

Answer (score 3):

Use @KJ50's solution, and use `savedInstanceState` to make sure you don't get a null.

```
/**
     * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
     * app
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // save file url in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation
        // changes
        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // get the file url
        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out below code :

> ```
>  Button m_btnCamera;
>   ImageView m_ivCaptureImage;
>   String m_curentDateandTime;
>   String m_imagePath;
>   Bitmap m_bitmap;
>
>    //Start camera to caputre image.
>  Intent m_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
>   m_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImageUri());
>   startActivityForResult(m_intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
>
>  private Uri getImageUri() throws CustomException
>     {
>     Uri m_imgUri = null;
>     File m_file;
>     try
>     {
>         SimpleDateFormat m_sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
>         m_curentDateandTime = m_sdf.format(new Date());
>         m_imagePath = File.getPath() + File.separator + m_curentDateandTime + ".jpg";
>         m_file = new File(m_imagePath);
>         m_imgUri = Uri.fromFile(m_file);
>     }
>     catch (Exception p_e)
>     {}      
>     return m_imgUri;        
> }
>
>  @Override
>   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
>   {
>   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
>  if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
>     {
>         m_bitmap = ImageHelper.scaleImage(m_imagePath, 200, 200);
>             m_bitmap = ImageHelper.rotateImage(m_bitmap, true, m_rotate);
>             m_ivCaptureImage.setImageBitmap(m_bitmap);
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: `catch (Exception p_e){}` My eyes are bleeding.

Comment: Catching all kinds of exceptions and then ignoring them (without logging or anything) is sure to improve the robustness of your code :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_IMAGE_ID:

            Bitmap bitmap = ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(this.getActivity(), resultCode, data);

            if(data!=null){
                //set image view
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This code will help you**

The getData() method returns data only if Android version is newer than M, else it will return null result.

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                //Check Android version, as intent.getData() will return data only if v is above or equal to M otherwise the data will be null
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    Uri selectedImageURI = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "URI Path:" + selectedImageURI, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) imageReturnedIntent.getExtras().get("data");
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), photo, "Title", null);
                    Uri selectedImageURI = Uri.parse(path);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "URI Path:" + selectedImageURI, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code below.....

```
btn_capture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent cameraIntent = new  Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
        }
    });
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){


             if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
                 Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
                 img.setImageBitmap(photo);
             } 
          }

    }
```

Then finally you add below code to your manifest

```
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature>
```