# onActivityResult not called when launching camera intent?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera

I have an activity where click of button camera activity is launched . Sometimes onActivityResult is called and sometimes not . Even after restarting the device the onActivityResult is not called nor does it restart the current activity  . Any solution to this weird behavior ?

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String imageUri = data.toURI();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageUri);
        try {
            mBitmap = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // if result is ok returns the bitmap
        // mBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        new Thread(postTheImage).start();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error during capturing the image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId() == R.id.capture_image_button) {
            // Open the camera to capture the image
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you missing the override directive on onActivityResult?

Comment: Can that cause such a big issue . It works sometimes and stops working suddenly .

Comment: @Pork 'n' bunny does not work , onActivityResult is not invoked sometimes .

Comment: Can you show how it fails? Is this just the emulator?

Comment: Hmmm i am trying it on device . Htc one x and after opening camera 5-6 times the onActivityResult method does not get called . I am not sure why . Even the system logs do not seem to give any explanation . zi tried the code in samsung S3 and faced the same issue

Comment: What is the value of the constant `CAMERA_REQUEST`?

Comment: try this instead intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: Could be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424909/android-startcamera-gives-me-null-intent-and-does-it-destroy-my-global-varia

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing the camera activity with the information it requires. You need to supply it a file URI.

Please refer to the following

[onActivityResult returned from a camera, Intent null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558240/onactivityresult-returned-from-a-camera-intent-null)

Comment: This answer is not correct. You don't need to supply a file URI. In general OP's code should work just fine. You can request the camera to take a photo. It will return a thumbnail of the photo in the `Intent` parameter to `onActivityResult()`. The linked question has unfortunately not been properly answered :-(