# saving a picture in a place where the gallery will not be able to access it

Tags: android, save, android-camera, image-gallery

[how to put a picture in the internal memory of the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292674/how-to-put-a-picture-in-the-internal-memory-of-the-app/37293392#37293392)
this was my question , it involved putting a picture in the app, I want to be more specific.
What I needed was that the Gallery wouldn't be able to let me view the picture after it has been saved on the device

here is the code:

```
public class Add_Comment_Picture extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1;
    ImageView imageView;
    ImageButton button;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__comment__picture);
    //    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
        button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonCamera);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File file = getFile();
                camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAM_REQUEST);
            }
        });


    }

    private String createFileName(){
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        return "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_.jpg";
    }



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            int hasWritePermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            int hasReadPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            int hasCameraPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

            List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (hasWritePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissions.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }

            if (hasReadPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissions.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }

            if (hasCameraPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissions.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
            }
            if (!permissions.isEmpty()) {
                requestPermissions(permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]), 111);
            }
        }


    }


    private File getFile()
    {
        //File folder = new File("sdcard/camera_app");
        File folder = new File("sdcard/data/data/com.yuvaleliav1gmail.foodchain/photos");
        if (!folder.exists())
        {
            folder.mkdir();
        }
        mCurrentPhotoPath = createFileName();
        File image_file = new File(folder,mCurrentPhotoPath);
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "sdcard/data/data/com.yuvaleliav1gmail.foodchain/photos/" + mCurrentPhotoPath;
        return image_file;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       // String path = mCurrentPhotoPath;
        imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(mCurrentPhotoPath));
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 111: {
                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
                    if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        System.out.println("Permissions --> " + "Permission Granted: " + permissions[i]);


                    } else if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                        System.out.println("Permissions --> " + "Permission Denied: " + permissions[i]);

                    }
                }
            }
            break;
            default: {
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @vrund purohit: You misspelled the file extension, please correct as ".nomedia"

Comment: Just put the file in internal memory of your app. Galery app has no access to your apps internal memory.

Comment: greenapps , this is exactly what i wanted to do... how do i do that?!?!

Comment: Have a look at getFilesDir() and OpenFileOutput(), OpenFileInput().

Comment: `folder.mkdir();`. That should be `if (!folder.mkdir()) return null;`.

Comment: `"sdcard/data/data/com.yuvaleliav1gmail.foodchain/photos"`. That is not a valid external memory path. It should be `"/sdcard/data/data/com.yuvaleliav1gmail.foodchain/photos"` if you wanted external memory. Moreover its a bad idea to hardcode paths. You should have used getExternalFilesDir() here.

Comment: thanks! this helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Place the file in a folder with a dot at the beginning, for example `.myimages`
2. create an empty file called `.nomedia` inside the folder with the picture

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a folder with a name that starts with a dot, for example: AppName/.Images. Now save the image into that folder, gallery wont have access to the images in the folder AppName/.Images.