# Gallery intent.getData() returns null in onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery, onactivityresult

I recently fixed a [known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989010/android-samsung-camera-app-wont-return-intent-getdata) in my app that occurs on some devices; when the user takes a photo from an intent launched from my app, in the `onActivityResult` `Uri uri = intent.getData();` returns null. I managed to fix that in the [suggested manner.](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath) However I get the exact same issue when the user needs to Select a picture from his phone's photo gallery. The same `intent.getData() == null`.

Starting the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),     
R.id.SELECT_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

onActivityResult:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn =
    {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();
dataHasChanged(ACTION_PICTURE, filePath);
```

PS: Strangely enough if I start the intent like shown below I can get the `intent.getData()` but only if I use the "Gallery" app on my samsung s4 and not the GooglePhotos app.

```
Intent pickImageIntent = new Intent(
    Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
if (pickImageIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
    startActivityForResult(pickImageIntent, R.id.SELECT_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

I am unsure on how to proceed. I find the entire Android intents affair very confusing sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm giving you code for your reference:

Use following code after clicking pic from your app:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    // call android default gallery
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    try {
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // Do nothing for now
    }
```

Below code will be in your `onActivityResult()`:

```
        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
                if (extras2 != null) {
                photo = extras2.getParcelable("data");
                bitmap = photo;
                profile_imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                new ImageUploadTask().execute();
                }   
            }
        }
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: This works great if there was only one ImageView to set the img to... what if I want to use the same logic to load file for more than one ImageView? how does the code on onActivityResult knows which ImageView to set the photo to? Any tips?

Answer (score -1):

```
static final int REQUEST_GALLERY_IMAGE = 14;

----------
 Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_GALLERY_IMAGE );


 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      if (requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                imagePreview.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: at least explain your code to a little extent for better understanding

Comment: Usign this code i am getting different image that i have selected.